# Magento: Anchor Categories and Simple/Config Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

## The Situation:

All my categories are `anchor categories`. I have a big category tree with several levels in my shop. I am using `configurable products` and associated `simple products`.

- Sometimes I put a configurable product into a category (e.g. when simple products have different prices) but not its simple products.
- Sometimes I put all the simple products into a category but not their parent configurable product.

## The Issue:

Every product shows up in the right categories. In case a **simple product is add to a category** things on the `product view` page of that product are weird:

- The Breadcrumb doesn't show the correct tree path (home / product-name, instead of all the categories)
- The next-product button is not working

Is this a bug? Can I solve this by rewriting a controller action?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the configurable product and simple products in their same categories. And if you have a category listing page, maybe try using a cms block to load a specific category of products on a category landing page.

So for example, if you have Products>Electronics and you want to show electronics in the Products category, just add a cms block calling Electronics on the Products page so that the links will be their correct links (not /products or /product name).

But magento creates a root/product-name url for all items.

And being an anchor really just lets you use sort the items in that category by filters. Hope that helps